# Query all objects whose json field has the filter value

Tags: django-rest-framework

**Models.py**

```
class Apply(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    role = JSONField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

How to write a filter such that all objects whose role field (json) has the filter value:

API: GET - /api/application/?role=efgh should retrieve entries with id
1 and 2 out of the below:

```
+----+--------+---------------------+
| id | name   |role                 |
+----+--------+---------------------+
|  1 | abcd   |["abcd", "efgh"]     |
|  2 | abcd   |["efgh", "ijkl"]     |
|  3 | abcd   |["ijkl", "abcd"]     |
+----+--------+---------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```py
role = request.query_params.get('role')
Apply.objects.filter(role__icontains=role)
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#icontains